# Uniqueness of solution, Volterra integral equation of first kind

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, integral-equations

I am looking for a reference/proof under which conditions the following Volterra integral equation of the first kind has a unique solution:

$$H(x)=\int_0^xK(x,y)g(y)dy$$

with $x\in[0,1]$, $y\in [0,1]$ and $H(x)$ is a (weakly) increasing function and $K(x,y)$ is increasing in $x$. I guess that this is a contraction mapping and so a solution always exists, but for uniqueness I am not sure how to proceed further...

Could one say anything at this level of generality?

Comment: What are you assuming about $g$?

Comment: You certainly need $H(0) = 0$.

Comment: If, for example, $K(x,y) = H(x) = x$, you need $\int_0^x g(y) \; dy = 1$ for $x > 0$.  That won't  happen for a function $g$: you need a distribution, the Dirac $\delta$.

Comment: On the other hand, if $K(x,y) = 0$ for $y$ in some set $A$, then the restriction of $g$ to $A$ can be anything, so you don't have uniqueness.

Comment: Thank you Robert! I am assuming in fact that $\int_0^1g(y)dy=1$ (it is a pdf function in fact). It is true that $H(0)=0$.

Comment: In most function spaces, integral operators such as this are compact, and therefore are not surjective.  What may be confusing you is that when the operator $T$ is a strict contraction, $I - T$ is bijective, i.e. the equation $H = g(x) - \int_{0}^x K(x,y) g(y)\; dy$ has a unique solution.

Comment: It helps, at least to see where to look further! I still have to wrap my head around of what you have said, I am from a bit different field. But when $T$ is not a strict contraction, is there anything known as to the size of the set of solutions? For example, can that be the case that there are at most finitely many solutions? Or that solutions lie not "far" from each other (in any topological sense)?